# Ошибка при установки React

Tags: reactjs, redux

Выполняю команды

npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

Получаю такую ошибку. Все шаги пробовал - не работает. Подскажите, что это за .env файл и где он лежит.

Как  это вообще можно вылечить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас глобально установлен `webpack`, и его версия конфликтует с версией в `create-react-app`, из-за этого и ошибка.

Как устранить проблему:

- При правильном подходе к разработке у Вас нет надобности в глобально установленном **webpack**, поэтому лучше бы его удалить:

  ```
  # удаление глобального вебпака
  npm uninstall webpack -g

  # переустановка зависимостей приложения на всякий (команды ниже выполнять в папке приложения)
  rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json yarn.lock yarn-error.log
  npm install

  # запуск приложения
  npm start
  ```
- Если вариант с удалением не подходит по каким-то причинам, то отключите сравнение версий вебпака, что **не рекомендовано и не гарантирует правильной компиляции в дальнейшем**. В папке с приложением, на корневом уровне, создайте файл *.env*, со следующим содержимым:

  ```
  SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
  ```

  Структура проекта с файлом *.env*

  ```
  ├── /node_modules
  ├── /public
  ├── /src
  ├── .env
  ├── README.md
  ├── package.json
  └── yarn.lock
  ```

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно работает. Надеюсь этот вопрос ещё кому-нибудь поможет.